# How to plot time series graph in jupyter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have tried to plot the data in order to achieve [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c33Yj.png):

[image]

But I could not and I just achieved [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGG1t.png) with plotly:

[image]

[Here is the small sample of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu2OU.png)

Does anyone know how to achieve that graph?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have you written so far? What went good and what part you don't understand?

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-the-dataframe-with-to-clipboard/52413247#52413247)

Answer (score 4):

You'll find a lot of good stuff on timeseries on [plotly.ly/python](https://plot.ly/python/time-series/). Still, I'd like to share some practical details that I find very useful:

1. organize your data in a pandas dataframe
2. set up a basic plotly structure using `fig=go.Figure(go.Scatter())`
3. Make your desired additions to that structure using `fig.add_traces(go.Scatter())`

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# random data or other data sources
np.random.seed(123)
observations = 200
timestep = np.arange(0, observations/10, 0.1)
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=observations)
val1 = np.sin(timestep)
val2=val1+np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=observations)#.tolist()

# organize data in a pandas dataframe
df= pd.DataFrame({'Timestep':timestep, 'Date':dates,
                               'Value_1':val1,
                               'Value_2':val2})

# Main plotly figure structure
fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Value_2'],
                            marker_color='black',
                            opacity=0.6,
                            name='Value 1')])

# One of many possible additions
fig.add_traces([go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Value_1'],
                           marker_color='blue',
                           name='Value 2')])

# plot figure
fig.show()
```